Insert results from js function to snowflake table
I have a js function, that prepares a query, then executes it on snowflake and stores the result in variable:
function objectGet(db, view, schema, object) {
        const x = `select get_ddl('${view}', '"${db}"."${schema}"."${object}"') as "result";`
        const res = snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: x } ).execute();

if (res.next()) {
            return res.result
        }


Then I want to insert the result from previous function to the table, but it doesn't work for me. How can I insert those results to table?
 function add() {
      let result = objectGet(x.db, x.view, x.schema, x.object);
            let insertt = `
            INSERT INTO "Base"."Schema"."Example"
            (col)
            VALUES
            ("${result}")`;
            snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: insertt }).execute();



Doesn't Snowflake have prepared statements with placeholders so you don't have to do variable substitution directly into the SQL text?

Why don’t you do this in one step, not two, using INSERT INTO… SELECT

It is just an example, but I want to just know for more complex cases

The problem is the double quotes around the ${result}, you should use single quote instead, as double quote is reserved for identifiers.
So your "add" function should be:
function add() {
      let result = objectGet(x.db, x.view, x.schema, x.object);
      let insertt = `
            INSERT INTO "Base"."Schema"."Example"
            (col)
            VALUES
            ('${result}')
      `;

      snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: insertt }).execute();
}

You might also want to escape the potential single quotes in the variable just in case.
